# Single term for a refracting or a reflecting material?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a paper on telescopes and I am finding that there are many instances when I am talking on a relatively abstract level and I need to refer to a material that might be a lens but could also be a mirror.

For example:

> The first thing that the light hits is referred to as the primary
>   lens/mirror.

I am looking for a single word that could replace 'lens/mirror' or 'refractor/reflector'.  Does this term exist?

I thought *medium*, but I don't really think a reflector would count as a medium and also, the air itself would fall into that category, which I don't want.

Comment: *Plane*, *surface*, or *object*.

Comment: "light-bending component" - a mouthful, but that's the term used in this Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_telescope_parts_and_construction

Comment: @IanMacDonald Isn't a lens more than a plane though, and again, it is more than a surface. Got anything more specific than object?

Comment: The object itself may have a thickness, but the *first thing the light hits* is the *surface* of this object, or the *plane* of incidence.

Comment: "optical element" is the term used in this Wikipedia page to describe lenses, mirrors, beam splitters, diffraction gratings, etc. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_optical_element

Comment: If you want a term for the combination of two systems, it is called a [***catadioptric system***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catadioptric_system).

Comment: There's lots of phonosemantics involving reflection and refraction. Take your pick among the appropriate members of [the `BL-` assonance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/bl.pdf) class, as well as [the `GL-` class](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gl.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any definite term in English for this.  However, you can coin a term for your use.  For example:

> In the following discussion, I will refer to mirrors, lenses, and similar devices as *optical elements*.

From then on, you can say:

> In a reflector telescope, the captured light first interact with the primary optical element, which then directs the light to the second optical element.

Comment: Not very good, as this cuts across general usage (a telescope being an optical device).

Comment: @Nick2253 feel free to use `optical element` instead of `optical device` as used in the Wikipedia page I pointed out in the comments.

Comment: +1 Optical Element:  [A part of an optical instrument which acts upon the light passing through the instrument, such as a lens, prism, or mirror.](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/optical+element)